# I can't run sql request from PHP, Oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Help me. I can't run php script for select data from oracle. It doesn't runs. `Error code: Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00911:`

This is my sql code:

```
select dn.def,
       (select te.err_comment
          from crt.crt_transfers_error_messages te
         where t.error_error_id = te.error_id),
       t.amount,t.msisdn_from,t.msisdn_to,t.insert_date,t.confirm_date   from crt.crt_transfers t,
       crt.crt_transfer_statuses ts,
       crt.sc_dictionaries_nls dn where ts.sdct_sdct_id = dn.sdct_sdct_id    and t.trst_trst_id = ts.trst_id    and t.msisdn_from = 992909119113
    order by insert_date desc;
```

Comment: Post your php aswell.

Comment: $conn = oci_connect("ro", "roo", "tm.mmm.ru");
$query_1 = "select dn.def,
       (select te.err_comment
          from crt.crt_transfers_error_messages te
         where t.error_error_id = te.error_id),
       t.amount,t.msisdn_from,t.msisdn_to,t.insert_date,t.confirm_date
  from crt.crt_transfers t,
       crt.crt_transfer_statuses ts,
       crt.sc_dictionaries_nls dn
where ts.sdct_sdct_id = dn.sdct_sdct_id
   and t.trst_trst_id = ts.trst_id
   and t.msisdn_from = 992909119113
    order by insert_date desc;";
$s_1 = oci_parse($conn, $query_1);
oci_execute($s_1);
oci_fetch_all($s_1, $arr_1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ORA-00911: invalid character
>
> Cause: identifiers may not start with any
>   ASCII character other than letters and numbers. $#_ are also allowed
>   after the first character. Identifiers enclosed by double quotes may
>   contain any character other than a double quote. Alternative quotes
>   (q"#...#") cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as delimiters.
>   For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language Reference Manual.
>   Action: none

Looks, like you have a problem with the insertion of your variables into the SQL statement.

echo out the query right before you execute it, and you will probably find a php variable within that has not been replaced by its value